# Вопрос из разряда: тема для диплома

Tags: php, cms

Собственно, вижу, что эта тема тут довольно часто обсуждается=)).

Оканчиваю колледж, выбрал тему  заранее: создание CMS, так как и тема вроде бы избитая и количество этих самых CMS с каждым годом растет как на дрожжах. С PHP я на "вы", но потихоньку приучаюсь к здешнему синтаксису, и работа идет довольно шустро. Структура централизованна: существует ядро (синглтон), который и занимается всей черной работой (подключение модулей, загрузка страницы). В ходе написания было рассмотрено довольно большое количество движков (очень положительно могу отозваться о Symfony, в которой, в отличие от той же WordPress, многое сделано с умом и разложено по полочкам). Собственно возник такой вопрос: каким способом осуществлять загрузку страниц (URL вида mysite.com/?p=3)

Видел несколько реализаций в разных CMS. К примеру:

```
if (isset($_GET['c'])) {
    // Выбор контроллера.
    switch ($_GET['c']) {
        case 'shop':
            $url = 'shop.tpl';
            break;
        case 'basket':
            $url = 'basket.tpl';
            break;
        default:  
    }
}
```

что в общем-то неприемлимо...в конце концов было решено использовать нечто вроде шаблонов. Есть файл с содержимым

```
{TITLE}
{CONTENT}
{и т.п.}
```

скрипт парсит такой файл, находит указанные "переменные" и заменяет их на определенные значения. Но этот подход также плох тем, что не под каждую страницу подходит такой шаблон. И вновь приходится создавать отдельный файл, изменять его, к примеру так, чтобы просто получить другую разметку

```
{CONTENT}
{TITLE}
{и т.п.}
```

Есть ли универсальная реализация? Может кто-нибудь подсказать более красивое, с точки зрения логики и красоты кода, решение?

Comment: попробуйте написать cms на фреймворке, например Yii.

Comment: да нет...зачем мне всякие фреймворки, тем более, что запас времени на написание дипломки весьма ограничен, и тратить его на доскональное изучение Yii мне просто не хочется. Цель - написать что-то свое, нативными средствами, в целях самообучения, и не так, чтоб ну...совсем по-нубски...поэтому и спрашиваю=)) как-то так

Comment: фреймворки созданы не для того, чтобы замедлять выпуск проекта, а для того чтобы ускорять, если yii сложно - возьмите codeigniter, там дока простая и он хорош для того чтобы совместить написанное на коленке и не писать свою MVC модель.

Comment: слышать об эти фреймворках слышал, но пробовать не пробовал, поэтому о сложности восприятия того или другого и речи нет. Это скорее моральный принцип, разобраться во всем самому, как я и сказал нативными средствами, для повышения скилла. Не хочется привязки к какой-либо модели(какой бы хорошей она не была)...но за совет спасибо, фреймворки посмотрю

Answer (score 1):

Если все зависит от переменной GET['c'], то для подключения контроллера я бы написал что-то вроде (без switch/case)

```
try {
    if (!@include_once( '/controllers/' . $_GET['c'] . '.php' ))
      throw new Exception ('file /controllers/'.$_GET['c'].'.php does not exist');
} catch(Exception $e) {    
      echo "Message : " . $e->getMessage(); // или рендер 404 ошибки
}
```

А по поводу шаблонов - не стал бы использовать шаблонизаторы вообще, php сам по себе хороший шаблонизатор.

Так же создал бы какой-нить массив(а лучше объект), отвечающий за передачу переменные в шаблоне. А в контроллере писал бы :

```
function my_action() {
$View['my_var'] = 'var_content';
}
```

А в шаблоне уже писал бы что-то типа `<?echo $View['my_var']?>`

Comment: Вообще, это грубо очень. Серьезно, используйте фреймворки

Comment: ммм....как вариант...

у меня тоже получилось нечто похожее. Я просто присваиваю 

$page->content = 'значение';

и в шаблоне ставлю {CONTENT}

в принципе получается тоже самое что и вы написали. И количество страниц у вас будет множится точно также как у меня...спасибо за отзыв!